# Which BI solutions cooperate with Postgres database and aren't too expensive?

Tags: postgresql, business-intelligence

I'm looking for solution letting me and my team track changes in Postgres database with daily updates. Data doesn't have to be updated instantly, once a day is enough. We use Excel/Google Sheet reports based on CSV files generated from Postgres at this moment and we're looking for more handy solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with excel you could import the data directly with an odbc connection.

If you wanted olap capability you can do that with a tabular model within excel.

In general most BI solutions will work with any relational database via an OLE or ODBC connection. If the product doesnt have a native adapter you could use a 3rd party ETL tool to move the raw data to a db that is supported.

Comment: Thank you Peter! I'll check this out. I'd vote up your answer but I need 4 more reputation points.